# Copying excel data from closed excel to another excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Below code is working, but instead of copying the data on excel sheet which I am currently working its opening a new excel sheet with desired output.

I have assigned below macro to button to every 5 min if I click on button it should refresh the details

```
Sub extractDataFromClosedFile()

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim src As Workbook
Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\test.xls", True, True)

Dim iTotalRows As Integer
iTotalRows = src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count

Dim iCnt As Integer

For iCnt = 1 To iTotalRows
Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A3" & iCnt).Formula = src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b" & iCnt).Formula
Next iCnt

src.Close False
Set src = Nothing

ErrHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Debug.Print Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Describe in greater detail your actual goal: which worksheets in which workbooks are to be dealt with and to do what?

Comment: You are opening a `Workbook` and then trying to assign a value to `Worksheet` "Sheet6". This then places the value in your new `Workbook` ofcourse because you didn't define the `Workbook` that it needs to be placed in.

Comment: Goal:- I have a tool which generates excel report every 5 min and with VBA code its getting saved on my local drive. Now I want to copy report data to my excel file to generate to lookup. Looking forward for your help

Comment: Basically you want to copy data from WorkBook1 (Source Workbook (Local drive)) to another workbook, that is where the above code is running. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, Siva your are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way.

```
Sub GetData_Example1()
' It will copy the Header row also (the last two arguments are True)
' Change the last argument to False if you not want to copy the header row
    GetData ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.xls", "Sheet1", _
            "A1:C5", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), True, True
End Sub
Option Explicit


Public Sub GetData(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
                   SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range, Header As Boolean, UseHeaderRow As Boolean)
' 30-Dec-2007, working in Excel 2000-2007
    Dim rsCon As Object
    Dim rsData As Object
    Dim szConnect As String
    Dim szSQL As String
    Dim lCount As Long

    ' Create the connection string.
    If Header = False Then
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
        Else
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
        End If
    Else
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
        Else
            szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
        End If
    End If

    If SourceSheet = "" Then
        ' workbook level name
        szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
    Else
        ' worksheet level name or range
        szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
    End If

    On Error GoTo SomethingWrong

    Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    rsCon.Open szConnect
    rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

    ' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
    If Not rsData.EOF Then

        If Header = False Then
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Else
            'Add the header cell in each column if the last argument is True
            If UseHeaderRow Then
                For lCount = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
                    TargetRange.Cells(1, 1 + lCount).Value = _
                    rsData.Fields(lCount).Name
                Next lCount
                TargetRange.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
            Else
                TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
            End If
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "No records returned from : " & SourceFile, vbCritical
    End If

    ' Clean up our Recordset object.
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    rsCon.Close
    Set rsCon = Nothing
    Exit Sub

SomethingWrong:
    MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name or Range is invalid of : " & SourceFile, _
           vbExclamation, "Error"
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function Array_Sort(ArrayList As Variant) As Variant
    Dim aCnt As Integer, bCnt As Integer
    Dim tempStr As String

    For aCnt = LBound(ArrayList) To UBound(ArrayList) - 1
        For bCnt = aCnt + 1 To UBound(ArrayList)
            If ArrayList(aCnt) > ArrayList(bCnt) Then
                tempStr = ArrayList(bCnt)
                ArrayList(bCnt) = ArrayList(aCnt)
                ArrayList(aCnt) = tempStr
            End If
        Next bCnt
    Next aCnt
    Array_Sort = ArrayList
End Function
```

From here:

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win024.htm